# Can't install right Clang Verison on Windows 11

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, neovim

I currently have neovim install on my window 11 computer however, I want to run c++ code. I have a simple file that contains the classic *print Hello World* however, I have an issue when I use clang++ to run it:

```cpp
C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Testing>clang++ testing.cpp
In file included from testing.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\iostream:8:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\yvals_core.h:887:1: error:
      static_assert failed "Error in C++ Standard Library usage."
_EMIT_STL_ERROR(STL1000, "Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 16.0.0 or newer.");
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\yvals_core.h:514:5: note:
      expanded from macro '_EMIT_STL_ERROR'
    static_assert(false, "Error in C++ Standard Library usage.")
    ^             ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have used choco to install the latest version of LLVM and when checking the current version of clang, I have:

```cpp
C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Testing>clang++ --version
compnerd.org clang version 14.0.0
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Library\Developer\Toolchains\unknown-Asserts-development.xctoolchain\usr\bin
```

I have also installed visual studio code to download clang through there and run the code through visual studio terminal but get the same errors. Anything else I should try?

Comment: Protip: don't put project files in OneDrive

Comment: The error message says it's expecting Clang 16, but you seem to have installed Clang 14. Did you knowingly install Clang 16 or 14?

Comment: @Dai No I downloaded LLVM 17.04 which should have a Clang 16+ version but it's not showing up and not sure why.

Comment: Do you really need the Visual Studio-compatible version of clang?

Comment: The path is strange, as Chocolatey installs in "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin". And "compnerd" (real name Saleem Abdulrasool) and the "MacOS nature" of the path suggests that this clang actually belongs to a [Swift](https://www.swift.org) installation (Saleem has done a lot for the Windows port). I suspect that you have messed up your `PATH`.

Comment: Have you checked the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm` which might contain the clang 16.0.x used by Visual Studio?

Comment: @BoP I have just checked it and it seems that clang 16 exists here. How would I change the directory to where when I run ```clang++ hello.cpp```, to run the right clang version?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. I basically found the environment variable C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin and moved it up so that PATH can recognize it